# Swipe through the notification area and click on a notification in notification drawer in android device using appium and python

Tags: android, python, notifications, appium, uiautomatorviewer

I have an android audio recording app, which generates a notification when I click on the record button.

Notification at the top (notification area) is a 'recording' symbol. After swiping and moving on to notification drawer, I get a notification saying that 'the recording is in progress' and by clicking on the notification the recording app should come to foreground.

Same happens when I pause the recording.

I need to test if the notification is the one which I was supposed to get, or not.

How can I test it using appium and python ?

Using uiautomatorviewer I could not find the notified elements, above in notification area. 
Is there any other way to find these elements ?

I am using ubuntu 14.04

Thanks in advance for the help.